# Web Scraping with Beautiful Soup Python - Seesaw - The output has no length error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the comments from a website called Seesaw but the output has no length. What am I doing wrong?

```
import requests
import requests
import base64
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as req
from requests import get

html_text = requests.get("https://app.seesaw.me/#/activities/class/class.93a29acf-0eef-4d4e-9d56-9648d2623171").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")

comments = soup.find_all("span", class_ = "ng-binding")
print(comments)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no span element with class `ng-binding` on the page (these elements added later via JavaScript)

```
import requests

html_text = requests.get("https://app.seesaw.me/#/activities/class/class.93a29acf-0eef-4d4e-9d56-9648d2623171").text
print(f'{"ng-binding" in html_text=}')
```

So output is:

```
"ng-binding" in html_text=False
```

Also you can check it using "View Page Source" function in your browser. You can try to use [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) for automate interaction with the site.